# Associative array loop order

Tags: javascript

I have an associative array (object) in wich I store data loaded from a 3rd party.

```
// 3rdPartyData is also an associative array
for(var key in 3rdPartyData) {
  cookie[key] = 3rdPartyData[key];
}
```

My object gets stored into a cookie at the end and gets loaded form a cookie before (or created {} if no cookie exists).

Each page view the data from the 3rd party gets added or updated in my cookie array.

**Question: If I wore to look the cookie, would the loop always get each key in the order they wore added to it or would the order be changed?**

**If so can anyone provide an idea on how to manage something like this?**

Comment: The order of keys in an object is trivial but you could make an array of objects.

Comment: @elclanrs "trivial" ? Is that the right word ?

Comment: JavaScript does not have associative arrays. You are probably talking about object keys and their order is not guaranteed.

Comment: @dystroy: I mean it doesn't really matter, because you have named keys right?

Comment: So how do you suggest I go about this? I don't really wan to crate a loop in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

The order of keys in `for(var key in some_object)` can be any, and certainly is not always sorted, but you can force the order to be the one you want:

```
for(var key in Object.keys(3rdPartyData).sort(keysSorter) {
    cookie[key] = 3rdPartyData[key];
}

keysSorter = function(a, b) {
    if (a === b) { // Should not actually be the case when sorting object keys
        return 0; 
    }
    // Compare a and b somehow and return 1 or -1 accordingly
    return a < b ? 1 : -1;
}
```

And to make sure `Object.keys()` will work:

```
Object.keys = Object.keys || function(o) {  
    var result = [];  
    for(var name in o) {  
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(name))  
            result.push(name);  
        }  
    return result;  
};
```

Comment: Note, that `Object.keys(3rdPartyData)` is not supported in EVERY browser. IE<9 doesn't have this.

Comment: Yes, but it can be easily added...

Comment: @Olegas: You mean "is not supported in *every* browser" I presume. Firefox and Chrome support it.